# SingleOrDefault: How to change the default values?

Tags: linq

SingleOrDefault returns null, but what if I want to assign values to represent the object that wasn't found?

Comment: did you find any answer?
you can not change default as promises by method. because SingleOrDefault should be SingleOrNull but it can return value object. 
who can tell return 0 for int, it is default or supposed number? 
SingleOrDefault can return 0 but it must not be default.
return null or not. it is bad paradigm for OOP.

Answer (score 54):

you can do something like

```
myStrings.DefaultIfEmpty("myDefaultString").Single()
```

check out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx)

Answer (score 24):

[?? operator](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/20/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq.aspx). If the left argument is null, evaluate and return the second argument.

```
myCollection.SingleOrDefault() ?? new[]{new Item(...)}
```

This will only work with reference types (or nullables), but it would do what you're looking for very simply.

Comment: A little round of applause goes off in my head when I get to use null coalescence. +1

Comment: @Joe I think the OP actually wants to change the default value that's directly returned from SingleOrDefault(), e.g. if searching for a Person object and none exist then he might want SingleOrDefault() to return a NullPerson object.  My understanding is that it isn't possible to change the return type and the problem must be solved the way you did it, but again I think it's important to clarify for the OP that the default return value of SingleOrDefault() can't be changed.

Comment: Does not work for collection of value types. 
For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424968/dictionary-firstordefault-how-to-determine-if-a-result-was-found

Answer (score 5):

You could roll your own.

```
public static T SingleOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T defaultValue) {
  if ( 1 != enumerable.Count() ) {
    return defaultValue;
  }
  return enumerable.Single();
}
```

This can be a bit expensive though because Count() requires you to process the entire collection and can be fairly expensive to run.  It would be better to either call Single, catch the InvalidOperationException or roll a IsSingle method

```
public static bool IsSingle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
  using ( var e = enumerable.GetEnumerator() ) {
    return e.MoveNext() && !e.MoveNext();
  }
}

public static T SingleOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T defaultValue) {
  if ( !enumerable.IsSingle() ) {
    if( enumerable.IsEmpty() ) { 
      return defaultValue;
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException("More than one element");
  }
  return enumerable.Single();
}
```

Comment: This would return the default value if the enumerable contained multiple objects.  Shouldn't it throw an exception like the standard implementation does?

Comment: @tvanfosson yeah it should. I was under the impression that SingleOrDefault would return the default value if there was anything other than one element.  But it apparently will only do so for no elements.  Weird, I will update.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own extension methods -- SingleOrNew.

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static T SingleOrNew<T>( this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, T newValue )
    {
        T elem = enumeration.SingleOrDefault();
        if (elem == null)
        {
            return newValue;
        }
        return elem;
    }

    public static T SingleOrNew<T>( this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Func<T,bool> predicate, T newValue )
    {
        T elem = enumeration.SingleOrDefault( predicate );
        if (elem == null)
        {
            return newValue;
        }
        return elem;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach though is you will return the newValue parameter for a collection which contains a single element with the value null. Consider this expression (new string[] { null }).SingleOrNew("foo");. It would incorrectly return "foo"

Comment: @JaredPar -- I'm willing to live with that.  Generally, I don't put nulls in my collections and were I to find one when using a method like this, I'd probably want to replace it with my default value anyway.

Comment: @tvanfosson, that's a fairly substantial breaking change from the original algorithm that makes a hefty assumption about how people use null.

Comment: The whole idea is that you use this when you want to guarantee that you don't get a null object, but one that's populated with a suitable default.  I don't see the problem.  Wrap the expected functionality in unit tests so that it's clear to the user what is expected.  Add some documentation if necessary.  I can't think of a single use case that this would break for me.

Comment: @tvanfosson, when designing an API you should consider other users before yourself.  In this case you're offering what amounts to an overload for an existing type of query yet your fundamentally changing the way in which it searches.  This may not break you but it will break someone depending on this behavior.  Consider as an example the difference between Hashtable and Dictionary.  In v1 it was considered OK to return null for Hashtable because it was thought no one would use null.  It turned out that was a very bad assumption to the point the changed the behavior for Dictionary in v2

Comment: I completely agree with Jared. You are making a huge assumption which could lead to very hard to track bugs. I would not recommend this approach at all.

Comment: @SolutionYogi just to be clear I'm not suggesting that Microsoft do this, but rather that one might do this for their project. For me, who never stores nulls in collections, this would be an appropriate solution to the problem.  If your collections might contain nulls then you'd need to perform your own check instead of relying on SingleOrDefault and only return the default when none of the elements meet the condition.