# Dictionary.FirstOrDefault() how to determine if a result was found

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have (or wanted to have) some code like this:

```
IDictionary<string,int> dict = new Dictionary<string,int>();
// ... Add some stuff to the dictionary.

// Try to find an entry by value (if multiple, don't care which one).
var entry = dict.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Value == 1);
if ( entry != null ) { 
   // ^^^ above gives a compile error:
   // Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,int>' and '<null>'
}
```

I also tried changing the offending line like this:

```
if ( entry != default(KeyValuePair<string,int>) )
```

But that also gives a compile error:

```
Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,int>' and 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,int>'
```

What gives here?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Jon's answer will work with `Dictionary<string, int>`, as that can't have a null key value in the dictionary. It wouldn't work with `Dictionary<int, string>`, however, as that doesn't *represent* a null key value... the "failure" mode would end up with a key of 0.

Two options:

Write a `TryFirstOrDefault` method, like this:

```
public static bool TryFirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, out T value)
{
    value = default(T);
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            value = iterator.Current;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, project to a nullable type:

```
var entry = dict.Where(e => e.Value == 1)
                .Select(e => (KeyValuePair<string,int>?) e)
                .FirstOrDefault();

if (entry != null)
{
    // Use entry.Value, which is the KeyValuePair<string,int>
}
```

Comment: You could also simply "double check" the result with exactly the same condition that you were looking for: dict.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Value == 1).Value.Value == 1

Comment: @YoupTube: That's one too many `Value` calls, and it won't do the right thing if the value you're looking for is 0.

Comment: Can someone explain how `TryFirstOrDefault()` is used? Where do I put my lambda expression and what is `value`? Is this only sample code?

Comment: @testing: There's no lambda expression to put in - `value` is an output parameter which receives the value of the first element of the sequence if there is one, or the default value of `T` otherwise, just like (say) `int.TryParse`. You could create an overload accepting a predicate if you wanted, but you don't have to - you can use a `Where` call first, as per the sample code.

Answer (score 65):

Do it this way:

```
if ( entry.Key != null )
```

The thing is that the `FirstOrDefault` method returns a [`KeyValuePair<string, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) which is a *value type*, so it cannot ever be `null`. You have to determine if a value was found by checking if at least one of its `Key`, `Value` properties has its default value. `Key` is of type `string`, so checking that for `null` makes sense considering that the dictionary could not have an item with a `null` key.

Other approaches you could use:

```
var entry = dict.Where(e => e.Value == 1)
                .Select(p => (int?)p.Value)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

This projects the results into a collection of nullable ints, and if that is empty (no results) you get a null -- there's no way you can mistake that for the `int` that a successful search would yield.

Comment: Fyi... The first option doesn't work for non-nullable types as the key

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites just check for the default value of that type... such as `0` instead of `null`

Answer (score 11):

Regardless of the types of Key and Value, you could do something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            {3, "ABC"},
            {7, "HHDHHGKD"}
        };

        bool found = false;
        var entry = dict.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == 3 && (found=true));
        if (found)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("found: " + entry.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not found");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

The clearest code I think is this:

```
if (dict.ContainsValue(value))
  string key = dict.First(item => item.Value == value).Key;
else
  // do somehing else
```

Though from the standpoint of speed it's not nice, but there is no better solution. This means that the dictionary will be searched with a slow search a second time. The Dictionary class should be improved by offering a method 'bool TryGetKey(value)'. It looks a little bit strange - because a dictionary is thought to be used in the other direction - but sometimes it's unavoidable to translate backwards.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static TValue FirstOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, bool> where)
    {
        foreach (var kv in dictionary)
        {
            if (where(kv))
                return kv.Value;
        }
        return default;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for nullable value types, just check.

```
if ( entry.Value != null ) { 
     //do stuff
}
```

for non-nullable types check againts default value, for int, 0.

```
if ( entry.Value != 0) { 
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: What happens if the value generic type is a non-nullable?

Comment: Good point, in that case we would need to compare the default value of that type. for Dictionary<string,int> then  (entry.Value != 0). In my case value type was nullable.

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, casting the object or using a select statement is unnecessary, I wouldn't rely on a try catch to fix the issue either.

Since you're using Linq anyway, what's wrong with using .Any?

```
var entry;
if (dict.Any(e => e.Value == 1))
{
    // Entry was found, continue work...
    entry = dict.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Value == 1);
}
else
{
    // Entry was not found.
    entry = -1;
}
```

Obviously, play with it to fit your solution, but it's a fairly quick check that stops if it finds an item in the collection with that value. So it won't check all values if a match has been found.

MSDN Documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Linq FirstOrDefault applying to a Dictionary returns not nullable keyValuePair object anyway.
The right way is to check result key or value that it doesn't equal default type value

Comment: The issue comes in here when default<T> is a valid key or value that might actually be in the dictionary.  For example, a dictionary with `int` keys where `0` might be one of the keys.