# How to get item from dictionary by value of property

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a `Dictionary<string, User>`.

`User` is an object with the properties `UID`, `UNIQUE KEY` and more. My dictionary key is the `UNIQUE KEY` of the users.

Now, i want to get a `User` from my dictionary values by a `UID` and not the key, something like `ContainsKey`.. how its done with lambda expr or linq? is there a good solution for that?

Comment: please post the code you have so far (if any). If you don't have any yet, write it and come back when you can provide an example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a working sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal class User
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, User> dic = new Dictionary<string, User>();
            dic.Add("1", new User { ID = "id1", Name = "name1" });
            dic.Add("2", new User { ID = "id2", Name = "name2" });
            dic.Add("3", new User { ID = "id3", Name = "name3" });

            User user = dic.Where(z => z.Value.ID == "id2").FirstOrDefault().Value;

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shorter notation: 

User user = dic.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Value.ID == "id2").Value;

And it needs a null check on FirstOrDefault as well to avoid NullReferenceException on Value ;)

Comment: Or checkout this answer with Don John Corleone Skeet for a discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424968/dictionary-firstordefault-how-to-determine-if-a-result-was-found

Answer (score 6):

```
return dict.Single(x => x.Value.UID == target);
```

Of course, you might find that your design is questionable if it involves continually doing linear searches across a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you'll loose the benefit of having a dictionary, but you can do someting like:

```
var user = dict.Values.FirstOrDefault(k=>k.UID==xxxx);
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` accepts an optional predicate that, if supplied, will take care of the filtering (i.e. `dict.Values.FirstOrDefault(k=>k.UID==xxxx)`.)

Answer (score 1):

This should get the user for the UID from the dictionary:

```
public User GetUserForUid(Dictionary<string, User> dictionary, int uid)
{
    return dictionary.Values.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UID == uid);
}
```