# How to make a custom Dictionary with different return code?

Tags: c#, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get null instead of the KeyNotFoundException accessing Dictionary value by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150508/how-to-get-null-instead-of-the-keynotfoundexception-accessing-dictionary-value-b)

I currently have lots of `Dictionary<string, T>` uses in my project, and most of them look like so:

```
if (myDic.ContainsKey("some key"))
    localVar = myDic["some key"];
```

It's not very effecient too, as it does two calls to the dictionary, which can be resource consuming. `TryGetValue()` is a cool thing, but it just doesn't do it in one line.

I just want to get `null` if there is no such key from `var v = myDic[key]`. How do I do that?

Comment: If you are not inclined to change your Dictionaries as mentioned in Konstantin's answers, a simple extension method which implements the null return would also work.

Comment: With Linq. you can do something like what was propossed in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424968/dictionary-firstordefault-how-to-determine-if-a-result-was-found

Comment: Side note: value types does not have have good notion of `null`... so beware of `Dictionary<string,int>` and trying to return "special non existent" value of type `int` :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov good point. When I solved this issue, I didn't have to work with dictionaries having values of value type

Comment: There's always an `int?` for those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do it like this:

```
class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue value;
            return TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : default(TValue);
        }
        set { base[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

It lets me use it like any other dictionary, through square brackets. Since I'm not going to use this with value types as `TValue`, I think it's good enough a solution.

Comment: What if I want to create MyDictionary<int, int>? How can I check whether key present in the dictionary or not?

Comment: @Lazin As I specifically mentioned above, I'm not going to use this with value types as `TValue`, and so shouldn't you. Alternatively, you can try using `MyDictionary<int, int?>`, or better yet `int?[]`.

Answer (score 4):

You may use an extension method with `TryGetValue`:

```
public static U GetValueByKeyOrNull<T, U>(this Dictionary<T, U> dict, T key)
where U : class
{
    U value;
    dict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    return value;
}
```

thanks to which you'll be able to write

```
somedict.GetValueByKeyOrNull("key1")
```

---

In the end trying to do this very thing I came up with a variant using a deriving from dictionary class with explicit interface implementation: [How to get null instead of the KeyNotFoundException accessing Dictionary value by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150508/how-to-get-null-instead-of-the-keynotfoundexception-accessing-dictionary-value-b)

That is

```
public interface INullValueDictionary<T, U>
    where U : class
{
    U this[T key] { get; }
}

public class NullValueDictionary<T, U> : Dictionary<T, U>, INullValueDictionary<T, U>
    where U : class
{
    U INullValueDictionary<T, U>.this[T key]
    {
        get
        {
            U val;
            dict.TryGet(key, out val);
            return val;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it instead of the original dictionary everywhere:

```
//create some dictionary
NullValueDictionary<int, string> dict = new NullValueDictionary<int, string>
{
    {1,"one"}
};
//have a reference to the interface
INullValueDictionary<int, string> idict = dict;
string val = idict[2]; // null
val = idict[1];        // "one"
```

Comment: Is there any way I could just use the square brackets, as with a normal dictionary?

Comment: @user1306322 did you read the thread I mentioned under this question? There you may find ideas

Comment: @user1306322 I've shared the ideas from that thread in this question. Please consider.

Comment: I understand it only serves a purpose of example, but I wouldn't recommend using a `Dictionary<int, T>` where `T[]` can be much faster.

Comment: @user1306322 this is indeed only an example. In reality both `T` and `U` are pf type `string`...I'd say, this is a little out of the question's scope

Comment: This is a good answer, so I prefer to return some kind of `Optional` type, that can contain value or not :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to deal with `null` so my implementation will look like this:

```
interface Maybe<T> {
    bool HasValue {get;}
    T Value {get;}
}

class Nothing<T> : Maybe<T> {
    public bool HasValue { get { return false; } }
    public T Value { get { throw new Exception(); } }
    public static const Nothing<T> Instance = new Nothing<T>();
}

class Just<T> : Maybe<T> {
    private T _value;
    public bool HasValue { get { return true; } }
    public T Value { get { return _value; } }
    public Just(T val) {
        _value = val;
    }
}
```

`Maybe` is a object that can contain value or not. Note that `Nothing` class contains static field `Instance`. We can use this value instead of creating new value each time we need to return `Nothing` from function.

Now, we need to create our own dictionary class:

```
class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dict;

    ...

    public Maybe<TValue> this[TKey key] {
        TValue val;
        if (_dict.TryGetValue(key, out val)) {
            return new Just<TValue>(val);
        return Nothing<TValue>.Instance;
    }
}
```

Advantage of this approach is not clear, because C# doesn't have pattern matching. But it can be emulated with `dynamic`:

```
void ProcessResult(Just<string> val) {
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}

void ProcessResult(Nothing<string> n) {
    Console.WriteLine("Key not found");
}

var dict = new MyDictionary<string, string>();
...
dynamic x = dict["key"];
ProcessResult(x);
```

I think that this is very clear way to express the fact that dictionary can't always return meaningful result. Also it is obvious for reader that function overload `ProcessResult(Just<T>)` will be called only for values that present in dictionary and other overload will be called in case when key is not found.

**Pros:**

- Type serves as a specification.
- Dictionary can contain both value and reference types.

**Cons:**

- More keystrokes.
- Little more complexity to deal with.