# Returning Default Value from List<> when match is not found

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to find a cleaner way of returning a default value when there is no match found. An example I have written to best demonstrate my question is shown below from `LinqPad`

So basically if given `Age` is not found in the list `SingleOrDefault` returns a `null` as normal. So instead of returning a `null` I pick the highest `Threshold` from the regardless of what the `Age` value is.

However instead of doing `if` or using `?? (null coalescing operator)` is there a cleaner way of achieving this? Perhaps setting a default value inside the `get` and `set` of Age property inside the `test` class?

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<test>()
    { 
        new test ( 55, 27 ),
        new test ( 56, 28),
        new test ( 57, 29),
        new test ( 59, 30),
        new test ( 60, 31) //60+
    };

    var res = list.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Age == 61);   

    if (res == null)
    {
        list.Max(l => l.Threshold).Dump();
    }
    else
    {
        res.Threshold.Dump();   
    }  
} 

class test
{
    public int Age 
    { 
        get;
        set;
    }   

    public int Threshold 
    {   
        get;
        set;
    }

    public test(int age, int threshold)
    {
        Age = age;
        Threshold = threshold;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure "cleaner" would be the term I'd use for a solution distributed over all the getters and setters of every property that might ever be queried on. And what if in some other query on Age, the desired default happened to be entirely different?

Comment: Using the null coalescing operator is probably the best readable/maintainable code in your circumstances. Note that you cannot really combine this in a query that would be easily readable/maintainable (in other words: even using a for/foreach loop would result in cleaner and better readable/maintainable code), as the enumeration has to be iterated first completely to determine whether there is actually a single matching "certain age" item before deciding whether an alternative "max threshold" item (based on a different selection critera than the "certain age" item) should be picked instead.

Comment: This has been asked many times, such as [SingleOrDefault: How to change the default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818642/singleordefault-how-to-change-the-default-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `DefaultIfEmpty()` of LINQ:

```
var res = list.Where(x => x.Age == 61)
              .Select(t => t)
              .DefaultIfEmpty(list.First(x => x.Threshold == list.Max(t => t.Threshold)))
              .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter this solved my query. `DefaultIfEmpty` Learn't something new today :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would like to have a LINQ method `SingleOrMax`, that you could use like this:

```
var res = list.SingleOrMax(x => x.Age == 61, x => x.Threshold);
```

The first expression is the predicate for `SingleOrDefault`, and the second expression selects the key that will be used for finding the max element, if needed.

Here it is:

```
public static TSource SingleOrMax<TSource, TMaxKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate, Func<TSource, TMaxKey> maxKeySelector)
{
    var result = source.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    if (result != default) return result;
    var maxKeyComparer = Comparer<TMaxKey>.Default;
    TSource max = default;
    TMaxKey maxKey = default;
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        var key = maxKeySelector(item);
        if (count == 0 || maxKeyComparer.Compare(key, maxKey) > 0)
        {
            max = item;
            maxKey = key;
        }
        count++;
    }
    // If you remove the line bellow, then rename this method to SingleOrMaxOrDefault
    if (count == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements");
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the above solution. Will try this out aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always go with an extension method, although it seems a bit overkill.

```
public static Test SingleAgeOrMaxThreshold(this IEnumerable<Test> items, int age)
{
    Test max = null;
    foreach (Test t in items)
    {
        if (t.Age == age)
            return t;

        if (max == null || t.Threshold > max.Threshold)
            max = t;
    }

    return max;
}
```